# mimic JS decodeURIComponent and unescape in python

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

I want to mimic the decodeURIComponent and unescape that we have in JS in Python.

For example I get this string:

```
%25D7%2590%25D7%2591%25D7%2592
```

in JS I can do this:

```
decodeURIComponent(unescape('%25D7%2590%25D7%2591%25D7%2592'))
```

and get:
    אבג

I couldn't find any way to do it in Python, I'm using Tornado Web if it's relevant...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's `urllib.parse.unquote` in Python (or `urlparse.unquote` in Python 2) to do that.

But I don't understand why the string you've posted is urlencoded **twice**. Because a single urlencoded string can be decoded just using `decodeURIComponent` (without the `unescape`).

Anyway, the Python version for this would be:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote # For Python 2 use: from urlparse import unquote

# decode twice because the string has been encoded twice.
unquote(unquote('%25D7%2590%25D7%2591%25D7%2592'))
```

For a single urlencoded string, you only need to use `unquote` once.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but just ran into the same problem. The data in the POST request changed the spaces to "+" instead of "%20", so I used encodeURIComponent to force it to "%20", but then, in POST, "%" is replaced with "%25". So in the end it looks like "%2520"... This is the reason why it's double-quoted ...

Comment: @kfinto you can use `.replace(/\+/g, " ")` on string as a CPU liter solution. Also code will looks much less confusing